# UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character even after formatting logger to use utf-8 encoding

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I am getting several of these errors from my logger in python.

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character *X* in position *Y*: character maps to undefined

Looking around on stackoverflow, I see that many people have been able to resolve the issue by telling their logger to use 'utf-8' encoding however for me the error still remains.

This is the function that I am using to create my loggers:

```
def makeLogger(name):
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s:%(name)s:%(message)s')

    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(r'C:\Users\lguarro\Documents\Work\SearchEngine_Pure\Log\custom.log', 'a', 'utf-8')
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    logger.addHandler(file_handler)
    return logger
```

As you can see I have explicitly told the FileHandler to use utf-8.

Here is an example of how I call my logger from which many errors originate:

```
self.logger.info("Starting url scrape for company, " + rec["Company"] + " using user agent: " + user_agent)
```

In particular the error typically comes from the characters inside rec["Company"] as there are a lot of weird company names in my database like lantm√§nnen unibake.

So what exactly am I missing?

Comment: The name of the company is "lantmännen unibake", so the names in your database seem to be broken or at least they were loaded using the wrong encoding.

Comment: Yeah actually I need to see if the source of my database is the cause for that or if it is something I did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was that I was using Scrapy and I was not configuring the root logger correctly and was only setting up the logger for each of my individual spiders (which behaves correctly)

In essence, I needed to add this to my execution script:

```
root_logger = logging.getLogger()
root_logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
handler = logging.FileHandler(r'C:\Users\lguarro\Documents\Work\SearchEngine_Pure\Log\scrapy.log', 'w', 'utf-8')
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s'))
root_logger.addHandler(handler)
```

For whatever reason, when I was trying to do the same thing using logging.basicConfig, it told me that "encoding" is not a valid attribute so I opted for this method instead.